# TFS - "the server folder is not mapped" followed by "path already mapped in workspace"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I am using a machine that was set up for me by someone else. I already have the code for various projects/solutions locally. When I try from Source Control Explorer to "Get latest version" it tells me "the server folder is not mapped". Fair enough, I use the dialog to try to map it - and get "path already mapped in workspace"

It's driving me nuts - I hope it is something simple!

I have not got server access, if that matters.

Comment: Check that another workspace isn't already mapped to the same folder. File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> workspaces.

Comment: The folder shown as already mapped in the Workspace I am already in. But still a "Get Latest Version" says it is not...

Comment: Is it mapped to you? What happens when you remove the mapping and reapply it? Are there any other mappings on that machine?

Comment: There are other mappings (other solutions), Does that matter? It is a private workspace, so I guess it is mapped to me?

Comment: The folders can't overlap in the workspaces. This is most likely your problem.

Comment: What do you mean `I have not got server access` ? Did you mean you can't access the local mapped sever path in TFS with your account?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I haven't got admin rights to access the TFS server itself through its web interface, for example.

Comment: Sorry Mike, there are NO other mappings for this particular folder in any other workspace (for other folders and projects, yes). In "Edit Workspace" the folder shows up as mapped to a local folder. In Source Control Explorer it says "Not mapped"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to switch to the corresponding workspace, then Get latest version.

1. Open **Source Control Explorer**
2. Change workspace in **Workspace** box.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Sorry to all the other kind people who scratched their heads over this for me, it was THAT simple. I had never at all even noticed that dropdown... as I said, too long away from TFS... (and I guess never with mutiple workspaces)

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is mapped by someone else as well you will not be able to remap it. You need to make sure the workfolder is mapped to that workspace and only mapped to you.

You could use [tf workfolder command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/workfold-command) to display information about the mappings between your workspace folders and the folders on the server for Team Foundation version control.

Also give a try with below workaround:

1. Try to copy your local source folder to another local path(back up),
   then delete this folder mappings.
2. Then remove the Working Folders in your current Workspace(or delete
   Workspace entirely). [Clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/).
3. Finally connect to TFS and re-mapping your TFS Source file to your
   original folder again.

Comment: "If the directory is mapped by someone else as well you will not be able to remap it. You need to make sure the the workfolder is mapped to that workspace and only mapped to you." Patrick, I am afraid I don't understand that, Do you mean someone else has mapped it (as another user) on MY machine ?

Comment: Yes, if the other user use your machine to  do the mapping  option. The folder will mapped with his account. And you will not be able to do the get latest option. You could use the command or 
[Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) to view your mappings(need some permission).

Comment: Hmm that could be the case. damn, I have spent too long with SVN/Mercurial/Git, I have either forgotten too much about TFS or it has got more complicated...

Comment: Ok looking at it with Sidekicks shows on my machine only workspaces owned by me, with folders that are mapped (just as "Edit Workspace" in VS2015 says).

Comment: @kpollock This must be a client side issue. It's hard  to determine the root cause.  Maybe cache, maybe something else. If  remove the mapping and reapply it and clear TFS/VS cache not work. The simplest way just like the workaround above, back up your local files to another path first, delete the folders/mappings or directly delete the workspace. And create a new workspace, mapping relationship in the original local path. Get latest from server and copy some changes back. Which should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The workspace box is on the top right of the window and usually hidden even if your Source Control Explorer is very wide.
[image]